# Is the asynctask always executed when swiping through fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Basicly I have very same code as described [here](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-swipe-view-tab-layout-example.html)   :

In each of the fragments I have different asynctask, that just fetches data from website.
It looks like this :

```
TextView text;
String content;
View today;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    today = inflater.inflate(R.layout.today, container, false);
    text = (TextView) today.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // ((TextView) today.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Today");

    new RetriveSiteData().execute("http://menza.lupajz.eu/?den=dnes");

    content = (String) text.getText();

    return today;
}
```

I am wondering if the data is always fetched, while swiping through fragments if the TabPagerAdapter class  (on the website)
has this methode implemented the same way

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        //Fragement for Android Tab
        return new Android();
    case 1:
       //Fragment for Ios Tab
        return new Ios();
    case 2:
        //Fragment for Windows Tab
        return new Windows();
    }
    return null;
}
```

In case if the data is always fetched and the asynctask is always executed how can I prevent that ? Maybe adding some onResume() methods to each fragment ?

Comment: Put your logic (async tasks) in fragment's `onStart()` method. See if there is any changes. Make sure you override those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two options:

1. Execute the async tasks only once in the activity that contains the view pager, and then pass the data to your fragment. You can do it with some lazy loading as well.
2. Use the ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int) function to set the number of fragment to be retained in the view pager. Default value is set to 1, and thus the getItem() method is called every time you switch. I don't recommend going with this option though, especially when you have complex and memory consuming views.